# Replace all words in a sentence starting with dollar signs

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to replace all elements of a string starting with a dollar sign.
Here you can find my example:

```
my_string <- "$AAPL $TSLA I recomend to buy $TLSA and to sell $AAPL; the price is rising to $12.56"
```

The replacement is the word `"cashtag"`.
Here is my desired output:

```
my_string
"cashtag cashtag I recomend to buy cashtag and to sell cashtag; the price is rising to $12.56"
```

I already tried it with `str_replace_all` and `startsWith`.
But so far I have not come to a solution.
I would also be very happy about a suggested solution using the tidyverse package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note than in a regex in R, you'll have to escape the `$` with a backslash, and then you'll have to escape this backslash with another backslash ;)

```
stringr::str_replace_all(my_string, "\\$[A-Z]+", "cashtag")
[1] "cashtag cashtag I recomend to buy cashtag and to sell cashtag; the price is rising to $12.56"
```

Comment: After OP's edit, we need + instead of *.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I forgot that only letters after the dollar sign should be treated. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using *gsub*:

```
gsub("\\$[A-Z]+", "cashtag", my_string)
# [1] "cashtag cashtag I recomend to buy cashtag and to sell cashtag; the price is rising to $12.56"
```

Comment: Another question: How can I replace usertags: `my_string<- "Hi, how are you @user1"`

The solution should be: `"Hi, how are you usertag"`

Comment: @TobKel replace $ with @.

Comment: No its not working. It is because also lowercase letters and also numbers follow after the @ sign.

Comment: @TobKel of course it won't work, we need lower case letters. `"\\@[a-z]+"`